# Music plays through phone speaker instead of headphones when app is opened?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, music, headphones, headphone-jack, speaker

This problem started a few days ago and it's extremely annoying in quiet environments.
I will be listening to music from any music player app, and whenever I open an app, get a notification, or switch the song the music starts playing from the phone speaker instead of the headphones. How can I stop this? Is this a software issue or a problem with the headphones itself? Is it just something in the settings? I've tried a lot of different methods.
Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? What's your android version? What is your device model?

Comment: This is happening to me too. I just reset everything to factory default and still experiencing the issue. Not sure where you can change profiles.

Comment: Do you use a custom rom? I've also used an S3 on stock ROM and this was not an issue. If you are using a custom Rom then I recommend informing the dev about the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Broken headphone jack or the profile setting might be changed, I recommend changing the phone profile and trying if not I'm pretty sure its a hardware fault.